# Why this regex match?

Tags: php, regex

```
echo preg_match("#/login#", "/login/val1-val2/dir2", $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

I get:

```
1
Array
(
    [0] => /login
)
```

The strings are not equals, how could I change my regex TO DO NOT match?

Thanks

Comment: Regex are not use to verify if 2 strings are equals. Regex are use to verify if a pattern match within a string. In your case, the pattern matches.

Comment: @LucM, see the draevor answer. He has understood what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this: `#^/login$#`. The `^` and `$` mark the begining and end of the string. Of course, if that's your exact use case, you can simply use `==` to "match" the strings.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just compare strings if you want to test for equality? Why are you even using a regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

The regex is matching because `/login` is a substring of `/login/val1-val2/dir2`.